# auto populate data with dropdown

Tags: php, text, drop-down-menu, field, populate

**ALL EDITED**

Hi,

How can I auto populate the data from db by dropdown selected? and my dropdown result already appear as well, the code as following:

```
<?php
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$customer_data.'</td>
    <td><select name="customer_id" id="customer_id" onchange="getCustomer();">';

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        if ($customer['customer_id'] == $customer_id) {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'" selected="selected">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>
        </td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

has html view code as

```
<select name="customer_id" id="customer_id" onchange="getCustomer();">
  <option value="8">admin</option>
  <option value="6">customer1</option>
  <option value="7"  selected="selected">FREE</option>
</select>
```

now if one of dropdown selected i want another e.g. `<?php echo $firstname; ?>, <?php echo
$lastname; ?>`

appear in

```
<tr>
<td><div  id="show"></div></td>
</tr>
```

that based on customer id/name selected

to do that i try to use json call as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function getCustomer() {
    $('#show input').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?p=customer/customers&customer_id=' + $('#customer_id').attr('value'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#show').append('<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="' + data[i]['customer_id'] + '" /><input type="text" name="firstname" value="' + data[i]['firstname'] + '" />');
            }
        }
    });
}
getCustomer();
//--></script>
```

the php call json placed at customer.php with url index.php?p=page/customer)

```
public function customers() {
    $this->load->model('account/customer');
    if (isset($this->request->get['customer_id'])) {
        $customer_id = $this->request->get['customer_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }

    $customer_data = array();
    $results = $this->account_customer->getCustomer($customer_id);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $customer_data[] = array(
            'customer_id' => $result['customer_id'],
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'firstname'       => $result['firstname'],
            'lastname'      => $result['lastname']
        );
    }

    $this->load->library('json');
    $this->response->setOutput(Json::encode($customer_data));
}
```

and the db

```
public function getCustomer($customer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
    return $query->row;
}
```

but i get the wrong return as following

[image]

is there someone please how to solved it to more better? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something on your PHP-Coding style:
For a PHP Code-Block, don't use new php-Tags for every line. Also, if you want an HTML-Output from PHP, you can use the echo-Method to do this. So your Code looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$customer.'</td>
    <td><select name="customer_id">';

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        if ($customer['customer_id'] == $customer_id) {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'" selected="selected">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>
        </td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

The thin is, every time the PHP-Interpreter finds an opening PHP-Tag, it starts Interpreting it's code, and when it finds a closing Tag, it stops doing this. So in your code, the interpreter starts and stops all the time. This is not very performance.

I guess you want to set the value of your text-fields? That's really not what PHP does. That is more a JavaScript thing, because it actually happens in the Browser, not on the Server.

Comment: thanks for suggestion much appreciate it, yes I want to auto fill the text fields (firstname, lastname) by selected the combo box, the data load from db, I know how to load the data, and You r right it seem need javascript/ajax/jquery to handling it, but could You please let me know how to fixed it, please?

Comment: You mean how to set the value in the Textfield, depending on which option was selected in your dropdown-box?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I edited my previous code completely, please have a look, I hope that enough to described what i wanted and please let me know what's wrong or is there the better solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
    success: function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#show').append('<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="' + data[i]['customer_id'] + '" /><input type="text" name="firstname" value="' + data[i]['firstname'] + '" />');
        }
    }
```

in Your JS AJAX call do this:

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('#show').append('<input type="text" name="customer_id" value="' + data['customer_id'] + '" /><input type="text" name="firstname" value="' + data['firstname'] + '" />');
    }
```

as Your PHP function returns ONLY ONE object. If You then loop over the objects property You loop over one character of the property value indeed...