# Auto populate based on dropdown selected, need help

Tags: php, javascript, populate, drop-down-menu

How can I auto populate the data from db by dropdown selected?
and my dropdown result already appear as well, the code as following:

```
<?php
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$customer.'</td>
    <td><select name="customer_id">';

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        if ($customer['customer_id'] == $customer_id) {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'" selected="selected">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$customer['customer_id'].'">'.$customer['name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>
        </td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

and the result of dropdown above listed as

- admin
- customer1
- FREE

loaded from following db

```
INSERT INTO `my_customer` (`customer_id`, `name`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES
(8, 'admin', '', ''),
(6, 'customer1', 'ok', ''),
(7, 'FREE', 'marj', 'om');
```

so whenever dropdown selected i want the all data below:

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td>
</tr>
```

also auto populate, it seem need javascript/ajax/jquery to fixed it, I was Wondering if someone could help me, and thanks in advance

---

**Addtion** JSON CALL

I have the json call already as following:
(let say this placed at customer.php with url **index.php?p=page/customer**)

```
public function customers() {
    $this->load->model('account/customer');
    if (isset($this->request->get['customer_id'])) {
        $customer_id = $this->request->get['customer_id'];
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }

    $customer_data = array();
    $results = $this->account_customer->getCustomer($customer_id);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $customer_data[] = array(
            'customer_id' => $result['customer_id'],
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'firstname'       => $result['firstname'],
            'lastname'      => $result['lastname']
        );
    }

    $this->load->library('json');
    $this->response->setOutput(Json::encode($customer_data));
}
```

and the db

```
public function getCustomer($customer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
    return $query->row;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do...try to re phrase your question so that one can understand it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You are using jQuery, You will listen to select change event and then do an ajax call for PHP function that will return the data. The data will then be outputed to the appropriate places. I advise to set id attributes for next tags: `<select>`, `<td>` for name, `<td>` for surname, like so:

```
<select name="customer_id" id="customer_id>...</select>

<td id="firstname"> echo firstname </td>
<td id="lastname"> echo lastname </td>
```

Then the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#customer_id').change(function(){
        $.post(
            "http://www.domain.com/my_php_script.php",
            {customer_id: $(this).val()},
            function(data){
                $('td#firstname').html(data.firstname);
                $('td#lastname').html(data.lastname);
            }
        );
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Supposing that Your `my_php_script.php` retrieves the data from database by given customer_id in `$_POST['customer_id']` and returns a JSON object like `echo json_encode(array('firstname' => FIRSTNAME_FROM_QUERY, 'lastname' => LASTNAME_FROM_QUERY));`

**ADDITION**:
There are two options how to solve it - in JS instead of

```
$.post()
```

You have to use

```
$.get(...)
```

**OR** in Your PHP script instead of

```
$this->request->get['customer_id']
```

You have to use

```
$this->request->post['customer_id']
```

at every place... This should do it...
E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#customer_id').change(function(){
        $.get(
            "http://www.domain.com/my_php_script.php",
            {customer_id: $(this).val()},
            function(data){
                $('td#firstname').html(data.firstname);
                $('td#lastname').html(data.lastname);
            }
        );
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: @shadyyx, many thanks for your attention an suggestion, I was fallow your code but it seem I have not get any lucky yet, so I edited my previous code by included the json call, please have a look, let me know how to solved it. thanks again

Comment: Hi, thanks again mate, I have use it, but seem won't work, no data populate. what I should do?

Comment: I recently posted my complete code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873723/auto-populate-data-with-dropdown please have a look that maybe easy to help me. thanks

Comment: Hi. Do You have Firefox browser with Firebug plugin installed? If not, install it, load the page and hit F12 to open Firebug. Go to "Console" tab (if it is not allowed, allow it) and reload the page to AJAX call being called again. Watch the output on the Console and se the "Response" tab under the Console. What is there? Or could You provide us live demo?

Comment: OK, I answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873723/auto-populate-data-with-dropdown - that should now work :-)